# Generic type in Retrofit does not work for flutter

Tags: json, flutter, retrofit

I'd like to have a generic RestApi definition via Retrofit

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
@RestApi()
abstract class TestAPI<T> {
  factory TestAPI(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _TestAPI;

  /// GET ALL
  @GET('/models')
  Future<BaseResponse<List<T>>> getElements();
}
```

However, it always throws an error saying that

> the method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.

I understand that retrofit doesn't know that the generic type is marked with a @JsonSerializable() annotation. But how can I let it know it does?

Comment: If you want to get dynamic data, just use a Map<String, dynamic> or List<dynamic>.